Facing issue in Out session the user using Identity in ASP.NET Core Web API
In the application, users are registered through Microsoft Identity. Now from admin side, I can deactivate the user and activate the user as well. 
But on deactivation, I want to logout the user from all the devices he is logged in but this is not working. 
[HttpPost("UpdateBuyerApplicationStatus")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateBuyerApplicationStatus([FromBody] StatusUpdateRequest request)
{
    var response = _buyerApplicationBusinessLogic.UpdateBuyerApplicationStatus(request.Id);
    var systemUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(response.Data.ToString());

    string reason = "";

    if (systemUser.Status == Framework.Enums.AccountStatus.Active)
    {
        systemUser.Status = Framework.Enums.AccountStatus.Deactivated;
        reason = request.Reason;
    }
    else if (systemUser.Status == Framework.Enums.AccountStatus.Deactivated)
    {
        systemUser.Status = Framework.Enums.AccountStatus.Active;
    }

    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(systemUser);

    if (systemUser.Status == Framework.Enums.AccountStatus.Deactivated)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    }

    string subject = "Application Status Update";
    string templatePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "templates", "buyerStatus_email_template.html");
    string bodyTemplate = await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync(templatePath);
    string reasonBlock = string.IsNullOrEmpty(reason) ? "" :
    $"<p>Your account has been deactivated for the following reason: {reason}.</p>" +
    $"<p>If you believe this is a mistake, you can contact us through this email or our support desk." +
    $" Please visit the following URL for our support desk: <a href='https://edmnetwork.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/4/group/21'>Support Desk</a></p>";

    string body = bodyTemplate
        .Replace("{{Name}}", (systemUser.FirstName + " " + systemUser.LastName))
        .Replace("{{Status}}", systemUser.Status.ToString())
        .Replace("{{ReasonBlock}}", reasonBlock)
        .Replace("{{Year}}", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());

    _mailManager.SendEmail((systemUser.FirstName + " " + systemUser.LastName), systemUser.Email, subject, body);

    return Ok(response);
}


Hi @Talha awan, what is your Program.cs like? What do you mean for not working? Get any error or cannot sign out?
